# dpkg error while upgrading distros

Tags: debian, apt

The following is outputted after typing apt-get upgrade.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  manpages
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/795 kB of archives.
After this operation, 284 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 24372 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace manpages 3.27-1 (using .../manpages_3.44-1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement manpages ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/manpages_3.44-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/getent.1.gz', which is also in package libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.11
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/manpages_3.44-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm trying to make the upgrade from squeeze to wheezy, which I think I did successfully, except upgrading causes this error. What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to run `apt-get dist-upgrade`, not `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: I ran the former already. Now just upgrading afterwards

Comment: Why are you installing Ubuntu packages on a Debian system?

Comment: Not sure, my /etc/apt/sources.list only has wheezy packages in it. Before upgrading though, I had ubuntu packages in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

`aptitude remove libc-bin`

caused this to happen:

```
     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libc-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10.11 (now)]

     Downgrade the following packages:
1)     libc-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10.11 (now) -> 2.13-38+deb7u8 (oldstable)]
2)     libc6 [2.15-0ubuntu10.11 (now) -> 2.13-38+deb7u8 (oldstable)]
3)     libc6-i386 [2.15-0ubuntu10.11 (now) -> 2.13-38+deb7u8 (oldstable)]
4)     libxi6 [2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1~precise3 (now) -> 2:1.6.1-1+deb7u1 (oldstabl
5)     patch [2.6.1-3ubuntu0.1 (now) -> 2.6.1-3 (oldstable)]
```

And now everything is fixed enough where I can make a backup and reinstall the OS

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mucked around with your system package sources in ways that you shouldn't have and now things are in a very inconsistent state.

While it may be possible with much work to recover from this, you'll never be certain about the ongoing stability of your system. As such, just install a fresh OS and restore your applications and data there.

Comment: That sucks. For the short term though, would I be able to continue ignoring this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you (or a previous sysadmin) mixed in some packages from ubuntu and it has a file conflict with a package you are installing as part of the upgrade.

You can override the error with.

dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/manpages_3.44-1_all.deb

This is usually a reasonablly safe thing to do. Especially with something unimportant like a manpage.

Comment: `dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/manpages_3.44-1_all.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/manpages_3.44-1_all.deb`

Comment: there is no manpages in archives/